# For the function $f(x) = 5x^3-2x^2+2x$, find the values where $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0$. Also, are all of these values abscissas of inflection points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know the title doesn't format that stuff like body sections, so I'll rewrite the question as well as provide my work thus far and explain where I'm having trouble.

For the function $f\left(x\right)=5 x^3-2 x^2+2 x$,

a) List the $x$ values where $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0$.

b) Are all of these values abscissas of inflection points?

Unless I'm reading the question wrong, it's asking me to find points of inflection, which I think I did. I have no idea what abscissas means, though. Here's my work so far, please let me know what needs to be corrected. It's formatted slightly weird because I'm self-studying through an online program that requires it to be so. :)

Step 1) $f\left(x\right)=5x^3-2 x^2+2x$

Step 2) $\frac{d}{dx}\left(5 x^3-2 x^2+2 x\right) = 15 x^2-4 x+2$

Step 3) $\frac{d}{dx}\left(15x^2-4 x+2\right) = 30x-4$

Step 4) $x=\frac{2}{15}$

So, for a), my answer would be $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0$ at $x=\frac{2}{15}$, right? And, for b), I have absolutely no clue...

Answer (score 1):

The [abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa_and_ordinate) of a point is just a (really weird/uncommon) way of saying "the $x$-coordinate of the point".

With that in mind, part B is basically saying: now test whether the point(s) you found in part A are inflection points. I'm guessing you've recently learned how to find/test inflection points. $f''(x) = 0$ is one part of the requirement... what's left?

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a ton!! <3